# How to dynamically resize GTK notebook pages

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, pygi

I've got a Python app that uses a `Gtk.Notebook` widget to display different pages. Each of these pages contain a different set of widgets, and I've noticed that the 'tallest' widget in terms of vertical space defines the overall vertical size of the notebook.

But I'd actually like my app to resize the pages to not waste vertical space, and adapt, that is, get resized to the same vertical size as the widget they contain. This resize should happen when I select each page.

[image: Test app showing undesired vertical space]

Here's the [sample code to generate this notebook](https://code.launchpad.net/~dpm/+junk/notebooktest) (the example contains a widget per page for the sake of simplicity)

So in short, how can I dynamically resize notebook pages upon selecting them, so that their vertical space is adapted to be the same as their child widget?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know a nice answer, but I have a work-around for you:

The basic idea is that you **need** a container widget as the parent widget in **each** page (do not place e.g. a label directly in the page), and you can hide/show everything except the container (If you hide the container as well, the page will disappear).

This solution should work for otherwise arbitrary widget hierarchies.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class NotebookWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('notebook.ui')
        self.builder.get_object('window1').connect('delete-event',
            Gtk.main_quit)
        notebook = self.builder.get_object('notebook1')
        notebook.connect("switch-page", self.on_notebook1_switch_page)
        self.on_notebook1_switch_page(notebook, None,
                                      notebook.get_current_page())

    def on_notebook1_switch_page(self, widget, label, page):
        for p in range(widget.get_n_pages()):
            container = widget.get_nth_page(p)
            if not p == page:
                for c in container.get_children():
                    try:
                        c.hide_all()
                    except AttributeError:
                        c.hide()
            else:
                for c in container.get_children():
                    try:
                        c.show_all()
                    except AttributeError:
                        c.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    notebookwindow = NotebookWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```

In my original answer I recorded and re-instated the requested sizes. This does not work in general, because the requested size is only a minimal size. I would have to record a maximum size, in order for this to work, though.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! I tested it to work on [rev 2](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/+junk/notebooktest/revision/2) of the example. However, when testing it with the real code it did not seem to work. I've tracked it down to be because there the widgets in the real app are not put directly inside the notebook page, but rather they are contained within a grid in each page. [Rev 3](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/+junk/notebooktest/revision/3) of the example illustrates this situation.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, as it's a valid workaround for the question. I'm still stuck with my code with the grid, though. I'm unsure about opening a new question since it will be too localized, but in any case, any ideas why the latest example code with the grid is not doing the resize? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'll think about it... But its always ok, when you wait a while before you accept an answer, maybe someone else knows something better. I think it would make more sense to un-accept my answer than to write a new one with a minor change.

Comment: @DavidPlanella ok, added a fix for your more general problem. My guess is that you will soon wish there would be a toolkit with a more pythonic syntax. If thats the case, have a look at [kivy](kivy.org) :-)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Ok, I'll unaccept the answer for now as suggested, and if no other one comes up, I'll accept it again after testing your fix :)

Comment: @DavidPlanella ok, I completely rewrote my answer. It should work now for arbitrary widget hierarchies (see answer). Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! I've tried it in the real app, but that does not seem to work there yet. I've figured I'd start testing it there directly, as the sample app does work with your suggestion. I've committed your changes on [rev 79](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dpm/qreator/trunk/revision/79), but I can't yet figure out why it's not working there. If you've got any suggestions, feel free to submit a branch, so I can properly credit you for your work in AskUbuntu as well as in the code :)

Comment: So it seems while this works in some cases, it is quite convoluted and in the end you provided a solution using Gtk.Box (or Gtk.Grid). Would you mind posting a quick answer, so that I can credit you for it by accepting it and thus closing the question?

Answer (score 1):

**IF** the actual notebook widget is not needed, but is merely a way to keep similar content together and provide a way to switch between them, then there might be better/simpler solutions. 
Here is one that was in the end used for [Qreator](https://launchpad.net/qreator):

the main idea is to use a container like a [Gtk.Box](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#boxes) (called `page_box` in the example below) and keep only one item visible.
You also need a list with the content of each page, each packed into a single widget (e.g. a [Gtk.Grid](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html#grid)).

```
for page in page_list:
    self.ui.page_box.add(page.grid)
```

Here `page_list` is a simple list of page objects, where the page object has a `grid` property (the Gtk.Grid containing all the page content).

At last, you need to provide a way to switch between the contents, e.g. with a set of buttons, each calling a switch method with the corresponding `page_id` when clicked:

```
def switch_view(self, page_id):
    # hide all pages
    for child in self.ui.page_box.get_children():
        child.hide()
    # show the single page that is active
    self.ui.page_box.get_children()[page_id].show()
```

This is not a literal answer to the question, but it might solve the same problem.